# Magento - what are the accessible attributes of a shopping-cart discount?

Tags: magento

I've created a number of shopping-cart-specific discount rules.

Now, when a Magento shopper finalizes his/her transaction, I'd like to be able to tell if / which discounts were applied.

In the array of purchased items (SKUs, QTYs, etc) ... are discounts their own "items" (e.g. with their own unique identifiers, qty applied, etc)?  Or are all the discounts lumped into one line item?

Any insight into this matter is appreciated!  If you really want to make my week, the ultimate response would have the raw output of an example shopping cart with items & discounts! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you want to access this data. Informations about quotes (content of your cart) are stored in following tables: `sales_quote_order` and `sales_flat_quote_item`. That's where the rules are applied for the first time. Placing your order this quote is converted to an order and stored in `sales_flat_order` and `sales_flat_order_item`. Concerning discounts there are same columns with the same information.

In `sales_flat_order` you have one line for your order  here the id of the used `Cart rule` is stored in `applied_rule_ids` and the name of your rule  in `coupon_rule_name`.   `discount_description` might also be interesting. The total amount discount is stored in `discount_amount`.

In `sales_flat_order_item` discount amounts are stored per item in a similar way. Here you can get `discount_percent` per item.

Comment: Great info, Simon - thank you.  I need to access the data after the order is placed in order to get QTY, SKU (or applied_rule_id), price, etc.