# Magento: Do discounts have "SKUs"?

Tags: magento

I'm trying to get the 'Rule Name' (which I believe is the unique identifier, yes?) from a discount that's been applied to an order.

Here's the lead-up code:

```
$order_id = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
->load($order_id);

$order_items = $order->getAllItems();

foreach ($order_items as $itemId => $item) {
```

I'm using `$item->getSku();` to handle the product SKUs ... will this also fetch the discount's unique identifier?

Thank you very much!

---

**Edit** AlanStorm makes a good point so I'll clarify:

The discounts I'm dealing with are "shopping cart rules" and, for this question, they are product-specific.

So that prompts a second question: how would I get the unique identifier of a "shopping cart rule" that was applied to the overall order (e.g. 10% off all items)?

Comment: Is this a "apply a coupon to the entire order" discount, or a "specific item is discounted through a catalog rule" discount?  Knowing this will help people better answer your question.

Comment: @AdamStorm - Good point, I'll edit to add clarity, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no they don't. They are stored per quote/order and additionally in each quote/order item. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989108/magento-what-are-the-accessible-attributes-of-a-shopping-cart-discount/16997484#16997484) here about what is available and what is not. So only `discount_amount` is stored in your order. You could use this to calculate your discount percentage or `applied_rule_ids` to load the rule and get information there.

Comment: So a discount's unique identifier is its `rule_id` BUT `$item->getSku();` will not return the `rule_id`?  If my understanding is correct, thank you

Comment: Yes, you are right. You could use `$item->getRuleId();` or `$item->getData('rule_id');`. In magento every model is identified by id. Only products have both, skus and ids.